# XCode 4.2 Slow performance

Tags: xcode, performance, macos

I have installed XCode 4.2 on my macbook with specifications 2.1 GHz and 4GB of RAM. On few projects which were created using older version of XCode, my XCode slows down too much. It takes above 1.8GB of RAM and CPU Usage of about 153%. As result, my machine slows down too much and I experience very poor performance. I tried deleting workspace file from the project file but it also did not help much. One thing what I have noticed in Activity Monitor is that with XCode, there are one or two instances of Git as well. Is it the cause of this problem? Git instance is taking around 30% to 70% of CPU usage. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Best Regards

Comment: I dont think its git instance, i have an imac with same amount of ram and 3.02GHz of processor but even then the my mac slows down so much with simple projects that i have to relaunch it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I fixed it by disabling SVN and Git plugins of XCode. Simply go to /Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugins

Now find IDEGit.ideplugin and IDESubversion.ideplugin

Change names of both of above plugins so that xcode will not be able to execute them in future. Now restart your xcode and enjoy better performance.

Best Regards